# Cannot access network printer from windows 7 PCs

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, printer, network-printer

We have several printers in the office - 2 are connected to the network via ethernet cables, and another is connected to our "server" (which is actually a Windows XP machine). The problem is that none of our windows 7 PCs can access the one that is connected to the server. When I go to add printers the one connected to the server does show up on the list of available printers. However, when I attempt to install it an error message appears saying "windows is unable to connect to the printer".

If I attempt to manually find the printer by typing in the IP address of the server it is connected to it claims that it cannot find it.

Has anyone else experienced this problem?

Thanks

Comment: How is your printer connected to server (usb, ethernet)? Is that printer installed on server? Which server system are you using?

Comment: It's connected via a printer parallel port. And the server is just a windows XP machine, not anything fancy like windows server. I believe it is installed on the server also. It's strange because all the XP machines on the network can access the printer - just none of the windows 7 machines.

Comment: Is that printer properly shared? Browse that server with unc path `\\xpserver\ ` , and select `Show remote printers`, is printer listed there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the printer can be seen, here is what I had to do in the same situation;

1. In Windows 7, from the `Devices and Printers` window, choose `Add Printer`.
2. Select  a `Add Local Printer`.
3. Choose `Create a New Port`. Then select `Local Port` from the drop down. Click `Next`.
   [image]
4. When prompted for the `Port Name` type path to the printer. It should be like `//XPMachineName/PrinterName/`.
   [image]
5. Follow the remaining prompts to choose the print driver you need and let Widows 7 install it.

Comment: Yes this is the answer! I did find this out several hours ago but it won't let me answer my own question because I don't have enough reputation!